# Why volatile static variable doesn't refresh?

Tags: java, static

I don't know how to achieve the refresh of a static variable. This static variable will be used as a *global* variable by all modules of the project. It's a boolean value storing a task state - done or undone.

At initialisation time, this value is set to `false` and will be set to `true` quite quickly, once the `Cache` is built.

The project looks like this:

```
Project
|-- Domain module (entities & DAO)
      |----- Services
                 |----- Cache
                 |----- class with static variable 'done / undone' (just to try, not definitive)
|-- Events Manager module (push data to Database & Cache)
|-- module 1 (pull data mainly from Cache, little from DB)
|-- module 2 (pull data mainly from Cache, little from DB)
|-- module 3 (pull data mainly from Cache, little from DB)
```

*EventsManager* processes data and create `Event` objects that are stored in a database and then in the Cache. Storing data in the database is mandatory, Cache helps to drastically limit requests to database.

At initialisation time, Events Manager has a specific task: it fetches all data from a table in the database and stores them in the Cache.

Modules 1->N are waiting for events to process. They periodically look in the database (a little) or in the Cache (mainly) to find new events to process.

All modules 1->N are built the same way and runs this method at initialisation time:

```
...
@Override
    public void run(String... args) {

        LOG.info(String.format("Starting %s Processor", PROCESSOR));

        /*
         * Every 30 seconds, fetches newest Event from Database
         */
        executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate( () -> {
            List<Event> eventFlux = getEventFlux();
            updateLastTimeValue(eventFlux);
            ConnectableFlux<Event> connectableFlux = Flux.fromIterable(eventFlux).publish();
            processEvent(connectableFlux);
            connectableFlux.connect();
        }, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
...
```

What I want to achieve is related to Cache building. All Modules 1->N have to know if Cache is accessible or not. It will once all data will be loaded from the database.

Once all data are stored in Cache, Events Manager set the boolean value to true.

```
public class OverallStatus {

    public  static volatile boolean cacheLoaded;
...
```

Modules 1->N have to read this value. The problem is that it always return false.

When I'm in debug mode, I can see that Events Manager sets this value to `true`, but other modules always read it as `false`.

I first thought that it could be explained by the fact that `executorService` keeps in memory the false value that was existing at initialisation time, when it has been scheduled.

That's why I added the `volatile` keyword to the `static` value, in order for this value to be refresh each time the `executorService` fires its task.

I don't understand why the `OverallStatus` object does behave like this. Whereas its value has been changed from `false` to `true` by the Events Manager, all other modules keep seeing it with the `false` value, just as if it was a completely different context.

Can someone explain such a behavior and, maybe, what kind of workaround could be found to get away with it? I've tried to found something related to my problem in [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4), but maybe I didn't understand all subtleties.

Comment: Are you setting it _reflectively_ to `true`?  The compiler is free to inline primitives that it deems never change, and I've seen that be the case with reflective access before.  You can probably check this by decompiling the place you're looking at the value (not in debugger) and seeing if the decompiled class does a field access, or just inlined.

Comment: Hi, 

I don't understand what you mean by "setting it reflectively to true".

Can you tell me what it means ?

Comment: I'll take that as a 'no' (I mean updating the value using java's reflection API instead of through `OverallStatus.cacheLoaded = true;`).

Comment: Oh sorry. No I don't use Field object to set the value

Comment: Could you replace the `volatile boolean` with a `final AtomicBoolean`, and then use the `get()` and `set()` methods to check/modify the value respectively.  This should have no problems with threading, and would let you know if it was your implementation that was wrong (if it still doesn't work) or your understanding of `volatile` (if it now does work).

Comment: What do you mean by module here? Are they in the same jar file? Do they use the same class loader? Maybe that class is loaded twice by different class loaders in those module

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/12867091/tashkhisi I don't know how to check if this is the same class loader or not. These modules are Java projects all linked in the same global project. They each have a POM.xml file and all modules (project) import the JAR of the "Domain" project

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2478398/beundead I've replaced boolean by AtomicBoolean. It still behaves the same. EventManager see it true while other modules see it false. When debugging I can clearly see that objects' ID are not the same. Just like there were 2 different AtomicBoolean

Comment: @Lovegiver Can you create a [mre] for us?  If your question is about a volatile static variable, we shouldn't need to know about all your databases and cache and whatnot.  This example should be completely separate from your program, it should compile/run, and it should demonstrate the problem with the least amount of extra code.  This would make answering your question much easier.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably 'module multi-loading'.

The point of a `static` variable is, of course, that there is exactly one variable for the entire class, and not 'one per instance'.

However, we have to zoom in on what 'class' actually means. It does **not** mean something like 'com.foo.lovegiver.Main'.

There is one class (and, thus, one instance of `java.lang.Class` that represents the class) for each combination of 'fully qualified class name' **and** 'classloader that loaded it'.

In other words, it is possible to have 2 different classes loaded that are both identical, are both named 'com.foo.lovegiver.Main', and are otherwise entirely separate. You can have an instance of one or the other. You can attempt to assign an instance of one of these to a variable typed "Main x", where "Main" is short for 'com.foo.lovegiver.Main', and you get the cryptic error of "an instance of com.foo.lovegiver.Main cannot be assigned to a variable of type com.foo.lovegiver.Main".

Each of the two same-name-but-different-loaders classes also has its own version of any static variables.

To end up with such a bizarre scenario, you need 2 classloaders. Each loader can load its own version of any class, with its own static variables.

Let's get to 'so what is a classloader'? It's not just calling some `java.lang.ClassLoader` instance's `loadClass` method. Because `loadClass` can end up actually asking some other classloader to do the work. The loader of any given class is: Whatever ClassLoader *actually* loaded it, which in turn is defined by: Whichever one invoked its native `defineClass` method on the bytecode.

The common design of classloaders is to first ask parent (this is how a system with classloaders does **not** end up having `java.lang.String` loaded hundreds of times: It asks its parent loader, which is the system loader, and thus there is only one String class: The one systemloader loaded).

However, [A] you don't have to; some classloaders intentionally don't ask parent and always load it themselves, and [B] if the class in question isn't on the classpath at all, then obviously the classloader will end up doing the work instead.

Given that you're using 'modules', it's likely this is what's happening. runtime module systems like OSGi extensively use classloaders. Same goes for systems that attempt to provide runtime-support for live reloading; some webservers let you just drop-in a new jar and will then 'update' automatically without restarting the server. There are a few ways to accomplish this; the most popular way is to notice the jar file changed and just spin up a new classloader for it: Voila, new classes.

An easy way to test if this is going on? The `java.lang.Class` instance representing the class will be different. So, print its system hashcode and compare.

In the code that sets the static variable to true, do: `OverallStatus.cacheLoaded = true; LOG.log("Set cacheLoaded to true for OS with sID: {}", System.identityHashCode(OverallStatus.class));`. And then in code that checks cacheLoaded, add `LOG.log("Checking cacheLoaded for OS with sID: {}", System.identityHashCode(OverallStatus.class));`.

I bet you'll get different numbers.

In that case, read the manual of your module system. Or, ask another question on SO, and ask how to ensure that you get a certain class loaded only once even for multiple separator modules, mentioning whatever's doing the modularizing.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/768644/rzwitserloot you're right, these are different instances of the same object. I thought that using "modules" was the way to make them communicate, but in fact I wander how it could be possible as they are different projects running in parallel.